# Using Ninject in a SOLID application architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, architecture, ninject, solid-principles

I'm starting with MVC3 and want to use some flexible architecture, so I've read tens of blogs, a book (Pro ASP.NET MVC 3), read about SOLID principles and finally got to an application structure I like (or at least I think so, so far, because I haven't built anything on it yet):

[image]

In this structure:

- Domain holds the POCO classes and defines the service interfaces
- Services implements service interfaces and defines repositories interfaces
- Data implements repositories interfaces
- WebUI and Domain use Services
- Services use Repositories
- WebUI, Services and Data depend on Domain for POCO classes

The main reason for Domain using Services is to validate unique keys on the Validate methods of POCO (IValidatable) classes.

I'm starting to build a reference application with this structure but I have faced, so far, two problems:

1. I'm using a Data.Tests project with unit tests for the repositories, but haven't found a way to inject (using Ninject) a implementation of the service (in the constructor or otherwise) on the model, so the Validate method can call the CheckUniqueKey on the service.
2. I haven't found any reference about hooking up Ninject to a TEST project (lots of for the WebUI project).

What I'm trying to achive here is beeing able to switch from EF to something else like DAPPER, by just changing the DATA assembly.

**UPDATE**

Right now (as of 09-AUG-2011) Ninject is working but I think I'm missing something.

I have a CustomerRepository with two constructors:

```
public class CustomerRepository : BaseRepository<Customer>, ICustomerRepository
{
    // The repository usually receives a DbContext
    public CustomerRepository(RefAppContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }

    // If we don't receive a DbContext then we create the repository with a defaulte one
    public CustomerRepository()
        : base(RefApp.DbContext())
    {
    }

    ...
}
```

On the TestInitialize:

```
// These are for testing the Repository against a test database

[TestInitialize()]
public void TestInitialize()
{
    // Context used for tests
    this.context = new RefAppContext();

    // This is just to make sure Ninject is working, 
    // would have used: repository = new CustomerRepository(context);

    this.kernel = NinjectMVC3.CreateKernel();

    this.kernel.Rebind<ICustomerRepository>().To<CustomerRepository>().WithConstructorArgument("context", context);

    this.repository = kernel.Get<ICustomerRepository>();

}
```

On the Customer class:

```
public class Customer : IValidatableObject 
{
    ...

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // I want to replace this with a "magic" call to ninject
        CustomerRepository rep = new CustomerRepository();

        Customer customer = rep.GetDupReferenceCustomer(this);

        if (customer != null)
            yield return new ValidationResult("Customer \"" + customer.Name + "\" has the same reference, can't duplicate", new [] { "Reference" });
    }

    ...
}
```

What would be the best way to use Ninject in this scenario?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

**ANSWER, SORT OF**

I'll consider this question as aswered so far. I could get Ninject working, sort of, but it looks like achiving the Dependency Inversion Principle (DIP) of SOLID is going to take some more time.

In that respect, I had to lump together Domain, Services and Data, I'll create another question some other time and keep the project going the usual way for now.

Thanks everybody.

Comment: Suggest taking out Ninject reference and change it to DI as the answer won't (and shouldnt change based on your specific container). I'd also add an architecture or find a few more tags.

Comment: @Ruben you are right, it doesn't sound quite right to use "Ninject" and "application architecture" on the same sentence, it's just in this case I'm trying to solve a problem very specific to Ninject.

Comment: I'd put the update into a new question as it is a completely other topic that has not a lot in common with the first one. Not a lot of people will read your new problem otherwise.

Comment: @Remo, You're right, besides that I realized I'm trying to do two complex things (for me) at once, son I'll first try to make Ninject work within a single assembly, and then I'll try splitting it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unit testing should be done without Ninject. Just create an instance of the object under test and inject a mock for every dependency manually.

For Integration Tests you can use the kernel inclusive all bindings from the application bootstrapper and **rebind** everything you want to replace by a Mock. e.g. Replace the Session binding by one that uses an in memory data storage instead of a real database.

Comment: Right now I'm doing integration testing, as I'm testing the repositories accessing the actual DB. The use of Ninject is to be able to eventually replace the services layer with someting else. In this case the POCO.Validate method is using a Service method defined in an interface. The point is, e.g. how do I resolve the service interface in the Customer.Validate method so I can use the CustomerServices.FindCustomerByEmail(Email) method to check if there's another customer with the same email.

Comment: @Miguel Veloso: Updated Integration Testing

Comment: where do I place the application bootstrapper? There is no Global.asax in a Test project!

Comment: Into the test setup. Call `this.kernel = MyProject.App_Start.NinjectMVC3.CreateKernel(); this.kernel.Rebind<ISomething>.ToConstant(new Mock<ISomething>());`

Comment: I tried this on [ClassInitialize()] but VS said I couldn't use "this" in a static method, and on the [TestInitialize()] and there the problem was the kernel member. Besides, I found several roadblocks, I updates the original question.

Comment: TestInitialize is the correct place. But I don't understand what you mean by the other problem with the kernel member. I assume you know how to add a member to the test class. So I think you don't consider this as the problem.

Comment: You're right, I was just tired and obfuscated at the time I wrote that.

Comment: I have it working with Ninject, thanks, everything is fine, but I think there should be a better way to use it, please check the updated question, is that right?

Comment: "Unit testing should be done without Ninject." I thought one of the main benefits of Ninject was unit testing!?  Right?

Comment: No - One of the benefits of injecting dependencies is that it gets easier to unit test your classes. But when injecting dependencies you have to put together your application somewhere. And Ninject helps to to that task.